# How to store arg and quoted arg value in bash variable?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have two scripts, printargs.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 1=$1
echo 2=$2
echo 3=$3
```

and passargs.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="-e \"hello there\""
./printargs.sh $arg1
```

How do I modify passargs.sh to pass two arguments, `-e` and `hello there`, to printargs.sh?  i.e. I would like printargs.sh to print

```
1=-e
2=hello there
3=
```

I feel like this question has plagued me for years!  The only way I can get it is by creating two variables.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer has been around for years.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
args=(-e 'hello there')
./printargs.sh "${args[@]}"
```